# RecyclerView displays only the first two rows on my device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my emulator, it inflates my view with 10 rows like it's supposed to do but when I run it on my device(Galaxy S4 v6.0)it only shows 2. I was using android v7.0 on my phone but downgraded to v6.0 to see if that's the problem but that didn't fix it. Running it on debug or release doesn't change anything.

```
button2nd.Click += async (_, __) =>
            {
               await mclass.GetSummonerInformation();
               iconUrl = string.Format("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/profileicon/" + MyClass.sumProfileIconId + ".png");
               DisplaySummonerIcon(iconUrl, imageView1);
               await mclass.GetSummonerMatchList();
               function1(); 

            };

private void function1()
        {
            game.Clear();
            mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is from the recentgamesdoworkcompleted");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (mclass.win[i])
                {
                    winorlose = Color.ParseColor("#42A5F5");
                }
                else
                {
                    winorlose = Color.ParseColor("#D32F2F");

                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is from inside the loop of recentgamesdoworkcompleted");
                game.Add(new Models.MatchHistoryListView()
                {
                    Name = "" + mclass.summonerId[0, i],
                    ChampionId = mclass.championId[0, i],
                    Id = i,
                    Score = mclass.summonerScoreText[i],
                    championPortraito = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/champion/" + mclass.championName[0, i] + ".png"),
                    Item0 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 0] + ".png"),
                    Item1 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 1] + ".png"),
                    Item2 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 2] + ".png"),
                    Item3 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 3] + ".png"),
                    Item4 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 4] + ".png"),
                    Item5 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 5] + ".png"),
                    Item6 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 6] + ".png"),
                    listViewColor = winorlose



                });


            }
        }
```

Main.axml here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <Button
                android:text="Get Summoner Information"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button1" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="378.5dp"
                android:layout_height="49.0dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="81.0dp"
                    android:layout_height="41.0dp" />
                <EditText
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:hint="Type your username here!"
                    android:layout_width="295.5dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="250.5dp"
                android:layout_height="113.5dp"
                android:id="@+id/summonerIcon1"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="Summoner Information"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Name:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/nameText" />
            <TextView
                android:text="User Id:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/userIdText" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Revision Date:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/revisionDateText" />
            <Button
                android:text="Get Mach History"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/matchList" />
            <Button
                android:text="Show Last Game info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lastGameInfoBtn" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView" 
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I would guess that your `View` only has enough room for 2 items to fill the parent. Thus you would have to post more code such as your layout XML.

Comment: Seems to be the nestedScrollingEnabled that is at fault.Disabling allows me to scroll through the recycler view that is at the bottom of the layout but i need it stretch and display all it's items.Removing doesn't give my desired look.Updated my OP.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using NestedScrollView from Android.Support.v4 since there is a known bug in API 23 and API 24 which causes the problem that i was experiencing.